# Realizar uma ação somente quando o app for iniciado pela primeira vez após a instalação

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um app em android que precisa mostrar uma mensagem ao ser iniciado pela primeira vez. Por exemplo: o usuário instala o meu app e executa. Nesta execução, o app mostra uma mensagem para que o app obtenha uma licença e o usuário clica em "ok" para aceitar os termos e liberar o uso do app.

A partir daí, a próxima vez que ele executar a aplicação, essa mensagem não deverá ser exibida novamente.

Tentei fazer um contador no `OnCreate` mas não deu. Há alguma coisa que eu possa fazer?

---

Meu `logcat` após inserir o código do usuário `@array`:

```
02-26 16:42:40.895: D/AndroidRuntime(818): Shutting down VM
02-26 16:42:40.895: W/dalvikvm(818): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.testegerador/com.example.testegerador.MainActivity}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.testegerador/com.example.testegerador.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818): Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.testegerador/com.example.testegerador.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5184)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
02-26 16:42:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  ... 12 more
02-26 16:44:05.165: I/Process(818): Sending signal. PID: 818 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Não entendo a utilidade da imagem, não seria melhor colar o código? Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Guilherme, o usuário inseriu a imagem apontando os erros que ele tinha encontrado no meu código, mas que já foi corrigido. Veja que eu tinha declarado a SharedPreferences como privada para o `onCreate`.

Comment: @Guest o ponto não é este mas sim tornar algo legível e de fácil "teste". :)

Comment: @Guilherme, ah, sim. Me desculpe. Acredito que o correto era: ou ele apenas editar com o código (como você disse), ou até mesmo mandar a imagem nos comentários da resposta abaixo (ele já comentou que havia um erro.).

Comment: @Guest realmente eu não li os comentários, mas não é bem você que teria que editar algo e sim ele formar uma pergunta usando o link que indiquei, a sua resposta parece boa, ainda não me atentei aos detalhes por isso estou um pouco por fora. Só pra dar um ênfase, somos uma comunidade de q&a, comentários são geralmente para discussões rápidas, códigos e erros relevantes a perguntas não devem ser postadas nos comentários, mas sim no escopo da pergunta :) eu acredito que você já saiba. Boa noite Guest

Answer (score 5):

Você tem duas opções: verificar se o aplicativo foi licenciado e não mostrar a mensagem, ou utilizar **SharedPreferences**.

**Opção 1**: digamos que você esteja utilizando um banco de dados para inserir a licença para o usuário. Assim seria mais fácil para controlar o acesso. Você pode inserir uma coluna no banco de dados (e.g: Coluna: temLicença) e depois pegar o valor dessa coluna e fazer uma ação.

**SharedPreferences** - Você pode ler mais sobre na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Com este método, você vai armazenar dados persistentes na memória do dispositivo. O manuseio dele é bem simples, veja o código:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sPreferences = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle cicle) {
        super.onCreate(cicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.SEU_LAYOUT.xml); // Coloque seu Layout aqui!

        // SharedPreferences
        sPreferences = getSharedPreferences("firstRun", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume();

        if (sPreferences.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {
            sPreferences.edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "primeiro launcher", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "segundo? terceiro?...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Lembrando que na condição `if (sPreferences.getBoolean("firstRun", true))`, ele verifica se é a primeira execução do aplicativo. Se sim, ele irá executar o código com a toast informando que é a primeira execução.

- O código estava com erro, mas já foi arrumado e testado.

Comment: Nesta parte do código: SharedPreferences sPreferences = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences("file_first_run", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Aparece um erro no "getSharedPreferences"
O erro é o seguinte: "The method getSharedPreferences() in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)"
E a opção que dá é para remover o getSharedPreferences()

Comment: Kaamis, acabei de corrigir o código. Refaça-o com a correção e me fale se funcionou. No aguardo!

Comment: Guest ainda ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Mais uma pergunta Guest, essa informação ficará salva mesmo se a aplicação for destruída e não só ocultada?

Comment: Kaamis, sim a informação ficará salva mesmo se a aplicação for encerrada/destruída. É uma informação privada ao desenvolvedor. Eu vou corrigir o código, já volto com ele corrigido e testado!

Comment: Kaamis, acabei de corrigir o código, testei, e funcionou! Estou no aguardo da sua resposta para confirmar se está funcionando ou não. Abraços!

Comment: Guest, não sei o que pode ser já que você testou mas aparece esse erro como na imagem que coloquei na pergunta agora. Eu tentei declarar a SharedPreference logo abaixo no public class MainActivity como dá pra ver e tirei a declaração do OnCreate deixei só o nome. Saiu esses erros mas na hora de rodar no emulador ela não roda, na verdade nem abre. Aparece aquele erro "Ufortunatelly...". Agradeço muitíssimo sua atenção!

Comment: @kaamis, mil desculpas! Eu tinha errado na definição da SharedPreferences, era pra ser global, mas acabei declarando como privada. Eu acabei de corrigir e, novamente, mil desculpas pelo erro! Lembre-se de modificar a linha `setContentView(R.layout.seu_layout_aqui.xml)` para o seu layout criado em `layout/`.

Comment: Guest eu modifiquei mas ainda assim deu erro "Ufortunatelly..." na hora de executar, não sei o que é mas mesmo assim obrigado pela sua ajuda e atenção!

Comment: Preciso que me mostre o seu `logcat`

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei o logcat.

Comment: @kaamis, já corrigi o código. Pode testar ele! O que estava faltando é que eu não estava chamando o método `super` para o `onResume`, causando o erro `SuperNotCalled`.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo array! Agora funcionou certinho! Eu tentei dar uma olhada no LogCat mas eu nao consigo entender quase nada. Agora eu dei uma olhada e vi a linha Caused by e a explicacao do erro logo na frente. Me corrija se estiver errada, o que vem acima seria o deccorer do erro e na linha Caused by o erro em si?

Comment: @kaamis, a linha com o `caused by` é um grande `resumo` do erro, ou seja, só com essa linha você já vai ter uma certa consciência do erro, mas já nas linhas acima, o erro vem desde o começo, ou seja, o erro vem totalmente detalhado, do início ao fim, algo como: Onde ocorreu, o que ocorreu, como ocorreu e etc.

Comment: Veja na primeira linha: `Shutting down VM` essa linha já diz que a máquina virtual foi encerrada, e nas linhas seguintes vai detalhando o erro até chegar na descrição: `Caused by: [erro]`