# Fazer com que uma Acitivity no Android apareça uma vez só

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Bom, minha dúvida é: Como eu faço pra que uma activity apareça só uma vez, e depois quando o usuário abrir o app de novo essa tela não apareça, apenas as outras. 
Vou explicar como é meu projeto pra ficar mais claro

Meu projeto é bem simples. São 3 Telas, a primeira de Cadastro, a segunda que é a "principal" e a ultima uma tela de recuperação.

Na primeira tela o usuário cadastra um e-mail e uma senha.
Na segunda ele usa a senha cadastrada pra conseguir Desligar o telefone.
E na ultima como falei, é uma tela recuperação de senha.

E eu queria que depois que o usuário fizesse o cadastro na primeira tela e fosse redirecionado pra segunda tela, a primeira tela não aparecer mais, eu só quero que ela apareça 1 só vez para o usuário se cadastrar e depois não mais.

Comment: Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51093/realizar-uma-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-somente-quando-o-app-for-iniciado-pela-primeira-vez-ap%C3%B3s-a-ins/51099#51099

Comment: As perguntas são diferentes, lá é quando a pessoa baixou o app, e quando ela baixar uma att não abra uma tela, lá ele mexe com versão do app o meu não, eu quero que a tela abra uma só vez e depois não mais, mesmo com att ou não.

Comment: Acontece que tu vai usar a mesma função para o  teu caso. Se o usuário se registar com sucesso, executar o código e salvar na SharedPreferences.

Comment: As perguntas são diferentes, mas a aplicação é exatamente a mesma. :)

Comment: concordo com a sinalização do @Ramaral pois o que o camarada quer pode ser facilmente conseguido com um splashscreen somente que ao inves de usar um timer use um evento onclick.

Comment: @array é isso mesmo. A(uma possível) abordagem é aquela, tanto nesta pergunta como na outra. Basta ver as respostas que foram dadas aqui.

Comment: @ramaral sim, as possíveis alternativas seriam salvar num arquivo .ini ou num banco de dados SQLite, mas acredito que `SharedPreferences` seja o melhor método.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce pode fazer de dois jeitos...
Um é usando o SharedPreferences pra salvar uma "tagzinha" e toda santa vez que for abrir o app vai ter que verificar se ela está lá e, se estiver, não abre a activity.
O outro jeito é salvar uma tagzinha no sqlite e fazer a mesma verificação, mas não recomendo. O sharedPreferences é assim:

```
    private void setSharedPrefs(Context contexto,
                                       String nomeProjeto,
                                       String chave,
                                       String valor) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        sharedPreferences = contexto.getSharedPreferences(nomeProjeto, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(chave, valor);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private String getSharedPrefs(Context contexto,
                                         String nomeProjeto,
                                         String chave) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        sharedPreferences = contexto.getSharedPreferences(nomeProjeto, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(chave, null);
    }
```

Uso:

```
        setSharedPrefs(this,"meuProjeto", "meuValor", "HAHAHAHAHA");
        String risada = getSharedPrefs(this,"meuProjeto", "meuValor");
        Log.e("funcionou", risada);
```

No seu caso, coloca tipo assim no oncreate da primeira activity:

```
    if(getSharedPrefs(this,"meuProjeto", "meuValor") != null){
       // Se tem algum valor guardado, chama o intent pra trocar de tela
    } else {
        // primeira vez que abriu, então seta o layout normal...
        setContentView(R.id.minhaPrimeiraActivity);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso caminho mais simples é salvar no SharedPreferences e checar se ja foi aberta essa tela para o usuario.

Comment: Eu tentei usar o SharedPreferences, só que eu acho que fiz o código errado, pois não mudou nada, eu fazia todos os procedimentos fechava o app, e quando eu abria pela segunda vez a tela que eu não queria que abrisse, abria mesmo com o código.

Comment: Depurou pra ver o motivo desse comportamento?