# Como criar uma tela de configuração em um app Android que aparece só no momento de cadastro do usuário?

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo [android](/questions/tagged/android) com autenticação pelo Firebase, preciso colocar uma tela em que o usuário definirá um "apelido", porém ele deve ser imutável. Logo, essa tela precisa aparecer logo depois do cadastro e apenas esta vez, ao acessar a mesma conta por outro dispositivo não deve ser possível alterar o apelido.

Encontrei algumas coisas sobre `SharedPreferences`, mas não entendi se os dados salvos assim ficam apenas no dispositivo, e como fazer isso com o Firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está utilizando o **firebase**, acredito que não seja preciso utilizar o **SharedPreferences** neste caso, pois como você quer definir um **apelido** **imutável** se caso ele não existir, você só vai precisar aplicar a lógica diretamente utilizando o **firebase**. O SharedPreferences é útil em casos de salvamento de configuração do aplicativo (como temas, cores, splash screens, etc). Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre **SharedPrefences** aqui: [Realizar uma ação somente quando o app for iniciado pela primeira vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51093/realizar-uma-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-somente-quando-o-app-for-iniciado-pela-primeira-vez-ap%C3%B3s-a-ins/51099#51099)

Basicamente, você vai precisar verificar se o usuário tem um apelido, se caso ele tiver, você não mostra a tela de inserção de apelido, caso contrário, você mostra.

O seu node, provavelmente, vai estar parecido com isto:

```
{
    "Users": [
     {
        "userUUID/Key": {
            "name": "Corey",
            "apelido": ""
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

E  a lógica aplicada será:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

db.child(db.push().getKey() /* UUID do usuario */).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.child("apelido").exists()) {
            // o apelido já foi definido
        } else {
           // o apelido ainda não foi definido
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, error.toException());
    }
});
```

Você também vai poder verificar se o apelido existe em outras instâncias. O que quero dizer é, se caso o usuário terminar o registro, mas não definir um apelido, você pode verificar se o apelido foi definido assim que o aplicativo é aberto, com essa mesma lógica, fazendo com que o usuário volte para definir ele. Pode ser quando o app for aberto ou quando o usuário entrar em sua conta.

Comment: você poderia me explicar melhor como criar esse node de users?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: Nós códigos do link acima ele salva no node `users` através do nome do usuário. O código da minha resposta diz para você salvar através da UID, que é aquele código próprio para cada usuário do seu app, entende? E assim tu vai salvar todos os dados do usuário nesse UID, que é único.

Answer (score 2):

Olá. O SharedPreferences não é uma boa opção, pois os dados ficam armazenados no próprio device. Se o user se logar em outro device, estes dados não estarão disponíveis. O ideal é gravar este informação no próprio Firebase, preferencialmente no Database. Crie um *node* do tipo usuario e use o UID do mesmo como chave: usuario/6rh7zl2aZXhAkUDlQdIjVLCx61r2/... Dentro deste *node* vc grava seu objeto usuário: nome, email, apelido, etc.
Dê uma lida no gravar e recuperar dados no Firebase Database:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=pt-br
Ao logar no seu app com sucesso, vc obter um UID pelo firebaseAuth. Com este UID vc recupera o objeto gravado e vai para tela principal do seu app. Se o firebaseAuth for nulo, vc redireciona para a tela de registro.
Espero ter ajudado.