# Criar novo node no Firebase

Tags: android, node.js, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de salas de bate-papo em Android utilizando o Firebase. A estrutura atual é a seguinte (sendo Assedio, Beleza etc salas):

[image: Estrutura atual]

Até o momento, os dados de usuário estão sendo armazenados com o padrão do Firebase, `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;`, porém preciso agora salvar um novo dado para cada usuário: um **apelido** que será definido apenas uma vez e **não poderá ser modificado**.

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225943/como-criar-uma-tela-de-configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-app-android-que-aparece-s%C3%B3-no-momento) recomendaram criar um node para usuário e salvar o apelido nele... Porém estou tendo dificuldade em entender essa parte de criar o node e salvar/modificar os dados. Acredito que seja simples, mas já li as referências do Firebase e não estou conseguindo implementar.

Agradeço se alguém puder explicar de forma detalhada ou recomendar um material sobre isso.

O código está em um repositório do Github, e o trecho com a criação de cada sala está neste [arquivo](https://github.com/Kathiani/android-start-master-facebook/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/friendlychat/MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ja dito, você pode criar um novo node, como por exemplo: "users" e dentro dele colocar todas as informações necessárias sobre cada usuário, como por exemplo: username, email, photourl, token e etc...

Por questão de segurança, defina as regras de acesso deste node no firebase-realtime-database na guia "regras" e adicione as permissões desse node, exemplo:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
  }
},
```

Neste caso, apenas o próprio usuário terá permissão de leitura e gravação destas informações.

Como referencia, podes utilizar a autenticação do google, mostrada no projeto de exemplo abaixo, na pasta auth:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

Com base nos dados recebidos após a autenticação, grave-os no node "users", algo parecido como o mostrado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se estas informações era o que estavas procurando, mas se precisares de maior detalhamento, informe nos comentários que vejo se consigo detalhar melhor a resposta.